# angularJS error: Error: n.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a third-party JS file to interact with an external API, that tokenizes data before sending.  In a simple test page, the function works perfectly fine and returns a token.  However, when I try to implement into my actual app that uses AngularJS, it keeps failing with the error: "Error: n.replace is not a function".

Here is the simple test script that works:

```
    // Click event handler
$('#form-submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#response').hide();

    var payload = {
        api_id: 'abcde123',
        var1: $('#var1').val(),
        var2: $('#var2').val(),
        var3: $('#var3').val(),
        var4: $('#var4').val()
    };

    // Tokenize data
    vendorScript.createToken(payload)
      .success(onTokenCreated)
      .error(onTokenFailed);

});
```

and here is the Angular code that throws the error:

```
app = angular.module 'MyApp'

myCtrl = ($scope, $http, $window, $q) ->

  myFormParams = ->
    api_id: 'abcde123'
    var1: $scope.var1
    var2: $scope.var2
    var3: $scope.var3
    var4: $scope.var4

  onTokenCreated = (response) ->
     # do real transaction here by using the onetime_token
     alert("The onetime_token created: " + response.onetime_token)
     $scope.checkoutPromise.resolve()

  onTokenFailed = (response) ->
     # do real transaction here by using the onetime_token
     alert("Getting onetime_token failed: " + response.onetime_token)
     $scope.checkoutPromise.resolve()

  $scope.submitForm = ->
    return if $scope.isProcessingOrder

    $scope.isProcessingOrder = true
    $scope.checkoutPromise = $q.defer()
    $scope.checkoutPromise.promise.then ->
      $scope.isProcessingOrder = false

    vendorScript.createToken(myFormParams())
      .success(onTokenCreated)
      .error(onTokenFailed);  

app.controller 'myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$q', myCtrl]
```

So, I've read previously about var.replace error being caused by var not being a string (thus not have a replace method); however, when I debug the original script, payload is passed as an object, just as myFormParams() passes as an object.  Furthermore, when I stringify myFormParams() ( i.e. "JSON.stringify(myFormParams())" ), the tokenization function fails.

Been banging my head on this for a bit; any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SoluableNonagon `null` or `undefined` would give a different error. It’s more likely that `n` is something other than a string.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Thanks for correction.